# Chipmunk with cocos 2d-x and iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, cocos2d-x, game-physics, chipmunk

I am developing a game for `iOS` using `cocos-2dx` to make the performance better, i have used `chipmunk` body added successfully but on run time when my sprite is moving on the screen the body stays on its original position let me paste the code.

```
 void TestGamePlay::onTouchesMoved(const std::vector<cocos2d::Touch *>&touches,cocos2d::Event *event)     
        {            

    auto touch = static_cast<Touch*>(touches[0]);
    auto touchLocation = touch->getLocation();
    cpVect v = cpv((touchLocation.x - littleFishBody->p.x)  ,
                    (touchLocation.y - littleFishBody->p.y)  );    
    v = cpv(250, 250);

    cpBodyApplyImpulse(littleFishBody, v, cpv(0, 0));

    cpBodyApplyForce(littleFishBody, v, cpv(0,0));
}
```

Here i have created the body.

`

```
float spriteWidth = sprite->getContentSize().width;
float spriteHeight = sprite->getContentSize().height;

spriteWidth = spriteWidth - factor;
spriteHeight = spriteHeight - factor;

int num = 4;

cpVect verts[] = { cpv(-13, -13), cpv(-13, 13), cpv(13, 13), cpv(13, -13) };

cpBody *body = cpBodyNew(1.0f,
        cpMomentForPoly(1.0f, num, verts, cpv(0, 0)));

cpVect t;
t.x = point.x;
t.y = point.y;
cpBodySetPos(body, t);
cpSpaceAddBody(_space, body);


cpShape *shape = cpPolyShapeNew(body, num, verts, cpv(0, 0));
shape->data = sprite;
cpSpaceAddShape(_space, shape);
littleFishBody = body;



this->addChild(sprite, 3);
sprite->setCPBody(body);
```

`
Kindly let me know where i am going wrong in it.

Comment: paste the code where you have created the body and added it to sprite.

Comment: @mohakagr i have updated the code please check